# How to write group by query returning results based on two different conditions on same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a table with data like shown in image below.[image].

How can I group the data so that I get the item name, num of rows, num of rows with quantity over 20 and number of rows with quantity less than or equal to 20. So the query should return results like:

```
Item,        num_rows, count_over_20, count_20_or_lower
Amazon Echo,  4,        2,            2
Apple iPod,   4,        2,            2
Google glass, 2,        0,            2
```

I could write a simple group by but not sure how to add columns for quantity over 20 and below.

```
SELECT item, count(*) as num_rows
FROM Sales
GROUP BY item;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT item, count(*) as num_rows,
       sum(quantity > 20)  as count_over_20, 
       sum(quantity <= 20) count_20_or_lower
FROM Sales
GROUP BY item;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee0a1/2)